# How to make logic gate combination using switches and bulbs?

Tags: circuit-design, logic-gates

> X         Y         F
>   0         0         1
>   0         1         0
>   1         0         0
>   1         1         1

Using min terms F(x,y) = X'Y'+ XY

The logic circuit for F needs And, Or, Not gates.

Using only switch and bulb,

> [image: Gates using bulb and switches]

So logic circuit for F will be-

> [image]

So how to make F using the switch-bulb AND , OR, NOT gates.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: @laptop2d no. It's project

Comment: that is a two-way switch arrangement that you probably have in your house ... one switch at top and one switch at bottom of stairs, both operating one light .... it is made with SPDT switches

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The representation of the NOT gate you are using is flawed -- there is no way to use its "output" as an input to another gate. (To put a name on it, this representation is not *composable*.)

If you allow the complement of an input (e.g, "not X") to be represented as a switch, it's possible to represent the function as this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiNkOZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you require each input to exist in a single place, though, it's impossible.

Comment: WOW. Thank you. The circuit for F you gave did not at all click in my mind. You solved my problem. Thanks.

Comment: I have one question- is there no way in circuit of F given by you, such that when A is open A' is closed and vice versa.

Comment: also your 'not' gate shorts the battery ....

Comment: @Taniwha yes, right. I had seen that NOT gate in a physics book, but the book also mentioned that "it is only an illustration" for not gate. Still I was trying to make F using thatNot gate

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the simple circuit to turn on a light bulb using switches at two ends of a hallway:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2flILsw.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Could you make for F= X'Y + XY'

Comment: Simply cross the 2 wires in the middle. Then one switch needs to be up and the other down or vice versa.